# Identifying intersections in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, intersect

I have two shapefiles: one containing a single polyline feature, and the other containing a number of polygons. I'm trying to use ArcPy to identify which polygons are crossed by the line, and then print some of their attributes.

Is 'intersect' the best process for this, or is there a better tool? Everything I'm reading about 'intersect' is suggesting that it will pull points of intersection as opposed to entire polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two similarly named "Intersect" processes in ArcGIS; one is a Geoprocessing tool called "Intersect" that would pull just the parts of overlapping polygons/lines that are common to both shapefiles. The other option is actually a subset of Select by Location.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm

Select by Location (overlap_type="INTERSECT" - or unspecified, as Intersect is the default) would pull the features from one shapefile (e.g. polygons) that intersect with the other shapefile (lines).